# Where do I need to escort Maurice Jondrelle?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I forgot where I should deliver this guy. I can't find anything in the quest log.

I could also kill him, but I would rather not do that. Where do I need to take him to finish the quest?

Comment: As you can't give that NPC any commands, you should consider cleaning the path to the Sanctuary before he accompanies you. Otherwise, he WILL annoy you by running towards every enemy in sight. It's impossible for me to kill all the Bandits on the way with a level 10 'Wizard' (highest difficulty though) without him dying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He wants to see the tree in the Eldergleam Sanctuary east of Whiterun.

> If you can get him there alive he will provide an alternative solution to the quest where you get sap from the tree.

Comment: It is also wise to note that he is pretty susceptible to death... Try run ahead of him and kill anything that may take a liking to him.